# How do I get stack_trace from Xdebug and build on top of it?

Tags: php, xdebug, xdebug-profiler

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to get stack_trace info from Xdebug similar to how an IDE like PhpStorm or NetBeans is getting it to store it and process it further.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: what settings do you have in your php.ini file for xdebug?

Comment: extension=xdebug.so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure (in your php.ini file) Xdebug to log trace into a file with xdebug.trace_output_XXX stuff. See [Xdebug docs](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings) for more information about how to fine tune your export and format output.

Comment: Thank you very much, I guess I could parse the log for now, while continuously search for any system software which latches on to XDebug and exposes an API. Best scenario, I end up creating my own

Comment: I've made kinda try to integrate trace. See https://packagist.org/packages/liqueurdetoile/taste